# Image ontop and behind of divs

Tags: css, html

Could someone help me out quickly.

Look at http://www.laebelliving.dk/ My idea is to place two images the same place, but behind and ontop of certain divs.

For example, i want a leaf to grow around my div content from behind and ontop of it. But i want this to be very cross browser friendly, so it will place the leafs at the exact same places of the page, no matter what resolution or browser they use..

How can i do this easily with css? :)

Answer to all the z-index answers:
Yea but how do i put the images exactly at the border of my div no matter what resolution people are viewing the website it, if you window size your browser and view it, you will see that the box size doesnt change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe use z-index:-1; for your images

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at z-index. 
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xY5Re/64/

Answer (score 1):

you can put the div and the images as layers by using CSS z-index :

[example here](http://www.quackit.com/css/properties/css_z-index.cfm)

Comment: Yea but how do i put the images exactly at the border of my div no matter what resolution people are viewing the website it, if you window size your browser and view it, you will see that the box size doesnt change.

Comment: use position absolute on your image and position relative on item where this image should be

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what all browsers needs to be supported.  My suggestion is to use cuss3 scale property along with z-index